# How to shift the values in a hash to another key

Tags: ruby, hash

I am having trouble figuring the best approach to shift some values to another key. Every value most go to the next key, and the last key's values need to be completely removed. For example

```
hash1 = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c: [7, 8, 9] }

desired_hash = hash1.some_method

desired_hash === { a: [], b: [1, 2, 3], c: [4, 5, 6] }
```

My thought is to rename the hash keys but was not sure if this was the best approach.

Comment: Do you have a reliable means of determining the "next key"? Do they really go `:a, :b, :c`? That would allow you to use `Symbol#succ`.

Comment: Would you like to say more about the higher level requirement?  There may be a better way to accomplish it that is not this exact approach.  Or does it have to be this exact approach?

Comment: The hash will be in a order but with numbers rather than letters. The problem is the same but changing the key names is not a must. Basically I just need to get every value from one key to the next. I know I could make a temp variable and save the values of each key and then go to the next key and overwrite them but this would seem more like an array kind of task.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're treating a Hash in a manner that'd be more normally done using an Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hash1 = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c: [7, 8, 9] }
keys = hash1.keys
=> [:a, :b, :c]
values = hash1.values
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

keys.zip(values.unshift([])).to_h
=> {:a=>[], :b=>[1, 2, 3], :c=>[4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you sir.

Comment: Note that you don't need the intermediate variables, `hash1.keys.zip(hash1.values.unshift([])).to_h` works just as well.

Comment: @Stefan, of course, I've added intermediate steps just for better explanation

Comment: I suggest that a better explanation is to keep what you have, but then explain how the variable can be substituted out.

Answer (score 1):

```
pv = []
hash1.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = pv
  pv = v
end
  #=> {:a=>[], :b=>[1, 2, 3], :c=>[4, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hash keys are "in correct order" already.
You can try this:

```
def shift(input)
  output = {}
  keys = input.keys
  0.upto(keys.size - 1) do |index|
    current = keys[index]
    if index > 0
      previous = keys[index - 1]
      output[current] = input[previous]
    else
      output[current] = []
    end
  end
  output
end

input = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c: [7, 8, 9] }
p shift(input)
```

it's not very elegant, there is probably a much nicer solution but it's a starting point.